# Twitter Streaming API with oAuth with Python

Tags: python, twitter

I've been trying to search for a good Module to in order to use twitter live streaming API and Python. I have found "tweepy" but it seems like it is using the "Basic Authentication" which is now deprecated. Is there any new module out there to use for that purpose that use oAuth?

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 0):

Tweepy has an oAuth module which works very well. See here: http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/auth_tutorial.html